# Arduino dc motor in sync with servo motor

Tags: arduino

I have this simple arduino code that drives two Dc motor using L298N  which is a motor driver together with two servo motors. The code is working fine for the motor driver but not for the servo motor:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
Servo myservo2;
int num=1;
int IN1=8;
int IN2=9;
int ENA=3;

int IN3=10;
int IN4=11;
int ENA2=4;

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(40);
  myservo2.attach(42);

 pinMode(IN1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(IN2,OUTPUT);

 pinMode(IN3,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(IN4,OUTPUT); 
}
void loop()
{
   intialPos();    

 while(motor_run())
  {
        turnOne();
       delay(3000);
       intialPos();
       delay(10000);
       turnSecond();
       delay(3000);
  } 

}
int motor_run()
{

  analogWrite(ENA, 1500);// motor speed  
  digitalWrite(IN1,LOW);// rotate forward
  digitalWrite(IN2,HIGH);

  analogWrite(ENA2, 1500);// motor speed  
  digitalWrite(IN3,HIGH);// rotate forward
  digitalWrite(IN4,LOW);

  delay(3000);
  return (1);
}
void intialPos()
{
  myservo.write(70);
   myservo2.write(135);
  delay(2000);
}
void turnOne()
{
  myservo2.write(170);
  myservo.write(135);
  delay(2000);
}
void turnSecond()
{
  myservo2.write(70);
  myservo.write(30);
  delay(2000);
}
```

My problem is to make the dc motor code continues to execute while the servo motor do its thing which is turning. But all it does was to make the dc motor work and the servo motors are unmoving. I'm using the servo motor as a rudder in a boat so I need to make the dc motor continuously working while the servo motor turns to a direction. I've heard multi threading but it is not supported on arduino. I found another way to make them in sync with each other which is using cycle or timing, but the sample code was confusing so can someone give me a code snippet and some detailed explanation for it.

Comment: Did you test your code with just the servo code? What kind of Arduino are using? (Since you are using Pins 40 and 42 for Servo attach.)

Comment: yes, I'm using the arduino ATMega..that's why it has 40 and 42 pin...the servo motor code alone works fine but when integrate with the dc motor it won't work

Comment: OK, since you have large, multi-second delays built in to your methods anyway, can you add a little debugging... At a minimum    Serial.printn("+motor_run"); at the beginning of motor_run(), and an equivalent before the return (1); statement... Then have a look at what's coming out the serial port?

Comment: Also, I notice that you are calling analogWrite(ENA, 1500).   analogWrite takes a byte value between 0 and 255. I wonder whether this might be causing some problems...

Comment: the analogWrite(ENA, 1500) is for the speed of the dc motor..Anyhow I would try the one you suggest above, about the debugging.

Comment: OK, but you need to change the 1500. Where did you get this value? You can only supply a value between 0 and 255 to analogWrite.

Comment: you're are right, the reason the servos won't run along side the dc motor is because of the delays I put on the functions to be called in the void loop()... And yes I'd change the 1500 to 255 because i thought it would make the dc motor run faster...but the dc motor's speed is quite slow for the  actual speed I want to achieve,so do you have any idea on how to make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who are curious on how i did it..this is the code with the little revision. Since I found out the movement is going backward not forward.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
Servo myservo2;
int num=1;
int IN1=8;
int IN2=9;
int ENA=3;

int IN3=10;
int IN4=11;
int ENA2=4;

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(40); // right side servo motor
  myservo2.attach(42); // left side servo motor

 pinMode(IN1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(IN2,OUTPUT);

 pinMode(IN3,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(IN4,OUTPUT); 
}
void loop()
{
   intialPos();   

 while(motor_run())
  {
       intialPos();
       turnOne();
       delay(3000);
       intialPos();
       delay(10000);
       turnSecond();
       delay(3000);
  } 

}
int motor_run()
{
  Serial.println("dc motor is working");
  analogWrite(ENA, 255);// motor speed  
  digitalWrite(IN1,HIGH);// rotate forward
  digitalWrite(IN2,LOW);

  analogWrite(ENA2, 255);// motor speed  
  digitalWrite(IN3,HIGH);// rotate forward
  digitalWrite(IN4,LOW);

  return (1);
}
void intialPos()
{
  Serial.println("servo motor in intial position");
  myservo.write(70);
  myservo2.write(135);

}
void turnOne()
{
  Serial.println("servo motor turnOne");
  myservo2.write(170);
  myservo.write(135);
}
void turnSecond()
{
  Serial.println("servo motor turnSecond");
  myservo2.write(70);
  myservo.write(30);
}
```